# change self password in murmur after self registration

Tags: mumble

I set up a murmur server, changed ACL here and there, managed to change the self registration password and registered another account to myself.

Now I want to change the password for this new non admin account from the default unregistered user server password to a different personal one.

Where can I find that option?

Comment: **The answer is in the Mumble [manual](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/FAQ/English)**

Comment: I already checked there and rechecked now: it seems it only tells how to change the SuperUser password and how a sysadmin can change a user password. I am looking for a way for user to self change their passwords from the client

Comment: The client does not have a way to do that.  You have to use a script on the server itself to change a user's password from my understanding on the subject.